# Write numpy array with special delimiters using jinja2

Tags: python, numpy, jinja2

I am trying to export a numpy array to a text file using jinja2 templating engine. The MWE file called `test.txt` of the template has the following content:

```
CUSTOM HEADER

{{ data|join('| ') }}
```

The desired output is a row ending with `|` and the delimiter between each element of the row is also `|` (e.g.: 1.0|2.0|3.0|) for a row with 3 elements.

I have tried the following:

```
from jinja2 import Template
import numpy as np

with open('./test.txt', 'r') as file_:
    template = Template(file_.read())
msg = template.render(data=np.random.rand(2,3))

print(msg)
```

However my output is not element delimited, nor have the opening and ending `|` as seen below:

> CUSTOM HEADER
>
> [0.62308496 0.97411965 0.8754648]| [0.78255269 0.33039354 0.24678549]

Any clues on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the join method as shown in the question, only the rows of the numpy matrix will be joined. To get the desired output, the following code can be used:

```
from jinja2 import Template
import numpy as np

template = Template("{% for d in data %}{{ d|join('|') }}|\n{% endfor %}")
msg = template.render(data=np.round(np.random.rand(2,3)*10, 1))
print(msg)
```

This will result in an output like:

```
2.0|0.1|1.3|
4.8|8.7|7.3|
```

Comment: Did not expect to have this answered at all by now. Thanks!